# Can't insert data into data base

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.5

i have written a code to insert data in data base its is

```
String sql="INSERT INTO check (name,pass,pno) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, name);
            pstmt.setString(2, pass);
            pstmt.setInt(3, no1);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

As i have avoided the sql injection and used preparedstatement i am still getting this error in my server log:

```
SEVERE:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check (name,pass,pno) VALUES ('Nikhil Muskur','qwerty1',7898455)' at line 1
```

i double checked it as nothing is wrong with the syntax then what is the problem can anybody help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check` is a reserved word in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Change your query to:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO `check` (`name`, `pass`, `pno`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

so MySQL understands you are actually accessing a table.

Answer (score 0):

('Nikhil Muskur','qwerty1',7898455) : update query by ('Nikhil Muskur','qwerty1','7898455')

7898455 must be an string value.